# How to run Java EE project remotely using JBoss AS 4.2?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, seam2

I am running a Java EE seam project at `http://localhost:8080/msh/login.seam?cid=1` using A JBoss server. My computer name is `pc-10`.

I want to access this seam project remotely at `http://pc-10:8080/msh/login.seam?cid=1`.

Could someone please point me in the right direction so that this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work unless you have some firewall or something.

In jboss as I remember by default its impossible to get to the remote server. So when running 
jboss you should define

`-b0.0.0.0`

parameter as an Ip-mask. This will tell jboss to accept connection from all servers in LAN.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i have already use ashttp://pc-10:8080/ the jboss server is running remotely but my application which is ashttp://pc-10:8080/msh is not running (my project name is msh) i have use run.bat -b pc-10